# Angular: Does anyone know how to delay a for loop in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sorting, for-loop

I am trying to create a sorting visualizer on Angular, and I decided to use the chart.js bar chart. I am trying to visualize bubble sort at the moment, and I would like to add a delay in every iteration of the inner loop. I am sure that you are familiar with the loop structure of bubble sort. I want to do the comparison, then call the draw function I made to draw the updated chart, and then after a 0.5 second delay, move onto the next iteration.

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {

      for (let j = 0; j < this.data.length; j++) {
          //comparison
            this.draw();
          // 0.5 SECOND DELAY
      }

}
```

Comment: you might need to look at animations https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/animations.html

Comment: this question has no relation with angular. its pure javascript or chart.js

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are better ways to manage the event loop in javascript than this, but i'll get you started:
jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zdfo5tce/

```
var data=[1,2,3,4,5]
var counter=0
let draw=(c) => document.body.innerHTML=c;

for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {

      for (let j = 0; j < this.data.length; j++) {
          //comparison
            setTimeout(draw.bind(this, counter), ++counter*500);
          // 0.5 SECOND DELAY
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will delay each iteration by 500 ms

```js
for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < this.data.length; j++) {
           setTimeout(function(){
             this.draw();
}, 500 *j);
      }
}
```